# How do I set culture for coded UI Test to get localised text from resource file?

Tags: localization, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

Scenario:
We have an application with localisation capabilities for which we doing automated testing with an extensive Coded UI Test suite. The UI text reflects the user's selected main language, e.g. French.

We have a number of message assertions to check specific results, and as a result we have to cater for the localised environment.

I have started on creating the localised Resources.resx files (e.g. Resources.fr-FR.resx) and set the CurrentUICulture to fr-FR, but the English string is always retrieved. (The Properties.Resources.Culture is always null, and even if I force-set it, no success...)

Any ideas on how to achieve this or where I'm going wrong? Do I have to force-deploy the assembly with the localised text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

OK, so I figured this out:
For coded UI tests, all the necessary assemblies have to be in the *..\TestResults\uniqueTestInstance\Out* folder. The language assemblies aren't copied here automatically, so what I've done is to add the following to my testsettings file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="RegressionCUIT" id="caf0f1b1-7dd7-4bbe-9920-edd664229791" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
    <Description>These are default test settings for a local test run.</Description>
    <Deployment>
        <DeploymentItem filename="Resources\TestData.xml" />
        <DeploymentItem filename="RegressionTesting\bin\Debug\de-DE\" outputDirectory="de-DE\" />
        <DeploymentItem filename="RegressionTesting\bin\Debug\fr-FR\" outputDirectory="fr-FR\" />
    </Deployment>
</TestSettings>
```

Note the *outputDirectory* attribute on the *DeploymentItem*.
Works brilliantly now.

Read more about file deployment here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx